# How to autorun multiple VBA macros upon open

Tags: vba, excel

I'm inside the ThisWorksheet code, have more code running in it and that works fine, and upon compilation I get an error saying it expected a function or a variable (then it puts the cursor on the name of the first program - "program1") 
I don't know if it is part of a security setting, but this is not working for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run Program1
    Run Program2
    Run Program3
    Run Program4
End Sub
```

PS: even when it does not error it simply does not execute the program (without "run" --just--> "module1.Program1")

Comment: When calling other subs, use Call subname

Comment: Change "Run" to "Call".

Comment: When simply using the name of the macro it simply does not run (no error, no explanation).

Comment: I haven't tried call. That probably will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: KFichter &  Grade 'Eh' Bacon - Yes... using Call fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: For the record in case anyone forgets how to use Call, there is a workaround: using run with a function which in turn runs a macro which is in the same module as the function....

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating a Function simply to call a sub instead of calling the sub in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Call "Program_Name".

Comment: `Call Program_Name`, without quotations.